# How to share source code when we develop Windows device drivers

Tags: windows, device-driver, nmake, wdk

> TARGETNAME=OneOfMyDrivers
>     TARGETTYPE=DRIVER
>     INCLUDES=..\inc;**..\..\Common\Crypto**
>     TARGETLIBS=$(SDK_LIB_PATH)\wdmsec.lib
>     SOURCES=OneOfMyDrivers.c \
>             OneOfMyDrivers.rc\
>             **..\..\Common**\Crypto\aes_modes.c \
>             **..\..\Common**\Crypto\aescrypt.c \
>             **..\..\Common**\Crypto\aeskey.c \
>             **..\..\Common**\Crypto\aestab.c

Without making a static library(in this case Crypto modules),
Can I build this makefile in this way. I don't know why it doesn't work.
I want to share the Crypto module's source codes with other drivers(and Apps)

Is it possible?
Is the only way a making a static library?

Comment: Has this got anything to do with msbuild? Are you hoping to port? What tooling version are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the correct way to do this is via building a static library. The DDK build system relies pretty heavily on them for sharing code between modules.